# Powermail: update database when confirmation link in mail is clicked

Tags: typo3, typoscript, powermail

I am using Typo3 v6.1.12 (I have to) and Powermail 2.0.18 with double optin.
You can store data from the formular via the dbEntry in TypoScript.
Is there a way to update these data when the link in the mail is clicked and the hash is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I dug a bit and here it was: Powermail only inserts the db-entry when it was already confirmed. So you dont have to do this in your own.

However if you want to hook into the confirmation process you have to use signals. In this case `optinCinfirmationActionAfterSuccessfulConfirmation`.